# Is there a way to turn off all labels in ArcMap without clicking on every layer?

Tags: arcmap, labeling

I rarely bother with labels, but sometimes it would be nice to toggle them on/off.  Something like the `Pause Drawing` button, except that it would only turn off labels (all labels in all layers...not just a single layer).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look on the Labeling Toolbar, there is a Pause button ([image]) that acts as a toggle for ALL labels.

[image]

Comment: this toolbar is available in ArcGIS v9.1 and above http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.1/index.cfm?ID=23&TopicName=What's%20new%20in%20labeling&rand=703&pid=20

Answer (score 7):

You can turn on dynamic labels for multiple layers at one time by opening the Label Manager and checking the box next to each layer.
[image]

**Suggestion:** Set Scale Ranges

Some labels are most useful within a given scale range. 
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Setting_scale_ranges_for_label_classes