# Interrupting label display with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling

In order to avoid slowness I would like to interrupt labels display when I'm working with ArcGis 10.

I read that the F9 key could do that but it doesn't work for me.
Does anyone know an other way to proceed, please ?

Comment: see also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-all-labels-in-arcmap-without-clicking-on-every-layer/4992#4992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Labeling Toolbar has a Pause Labeling button

[image]

The Pause Labeling button will stop labels from displaying until you're ready for them to draw.

> Pause Labeling - Suspends drawing of labels

See [A quick tour of the Labeling toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s800000014000000.htm) for more info.

To interrupt the labels while they are drawing, just hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for your answer and comment and sorry that this question has already been asked. Best regards.

Comment: Just done : excuse me, I forgot it ! :-)