# Controlling rule-based labelling using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, rule-based, qgis-3

Following on from this question: [How to turn on/off all labels of all layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226347/how-to-turn-on-off-all-labels-of-all-layers-in-qgis), OP mentioned in his [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226347/how-to-turn-on-off-all-labels-of-all-layers-in-qgis/226360#comment349980_226360) that he uses rule-based labels. I tried searching online as to how these types of labels could be read and modified but only managed to find this [post from lutraconsulting](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/10/25/rule-based-labeling/):

> In order to facilitate addition of rule-based labelling, some internal changes were made to the QGIS labelling engine interface. The labelling is now driven by the new class `QgsLabelingEngineV2` which may have several label providers associated with it.

Sounds great. However, when reading through the [QgsLabelingEngineV2 class](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsLabelingEngineV2.html), it mentions:

> this class is not a part of public API yet.

Is it currently possible to control rule-based labelling using python?

Comment: I found [an open issue here on the Qgis Documentation project in Github which also mentions this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/643). I couldn't find a SIP binding for that class in the MASTER or 2.18 branches, so I suspect it's still only available to C++ code.

Comment: @StevenKay - Great find, thanks! Would be quite useful if they did make an API for it...Also thanks for the edit, I thought I pasted the correct link for the class :)

Comment: @StevenKay - I think they made an API for this now, more specifically the [QgsRuleBasedLabeling Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedLabeling.html) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below some help to setup rule based labeling from scratch with the new QGIS 3 API

```py
#Configure label settings
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.fieldName = 'myFieldName'
textFormat = QgsTextFormat()
textFormat.setSize(10)
settings.setFormat(textFormat)
#create and append a new rule
root = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(QgsPalLayerSettings())
rule = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(settings)
rule.setDescription(fieldName)
rule.setFilterExpression('myExpression')
root.appendChild(rule)
#Apply label configuration
rules = QgsRuleBasedLabeling(root)
myLayer.setLabeling(rules)
myLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Unfortunately I can't find how to iterate over existing rules, the [labeling()](http://python.qgis.org/api/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.labeling) method available for vector layers return an object of [QgsAbstractVectorLayerLabeling](http://python.qgis.org/api/core/Abstract/QgsAbstractVectorLayerLabeling.html) class but it seems there is no way to get the root rule ([QgsRuleBasedLabeling](http://python.qgis.org/api/core/Rule/QgsRuleBasedLabeling.html)) from this class, the only possibility I found is to get directly pal settings using providers ids but I can't access to rules tree. Anyone have a clue ?

EDIT

It's now fixed, labeling() function return a QgsRuleBasedLabeling() : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/4b365a8f47d96b35f7609859e580388927ae0606

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nicely worked out! Hope you don't mind but I edited your post slightly to include `myLayer.triggerRepaint()` to refresh the layer and allow the labels to show immediately after setting the rules :)

Comment: It took me a while figuring out you may need to add a `myLayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)` to make the labels appearing...

Answer (score 4):

From **QGIS 3**, there is a new [QgsRuleBasedLabeling Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedLabeling.html) which would allow you to control rule-based labelling using the new API.

Rules can be added using [QgsRuleBasedLabeling::Rule](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedLabeling_1_1Rule.html).

---

(*Unfortunately, I cannot test the 2.99 version at the moment. But I would happily accept an answer if it provides a working example.*)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use to change a filter expression in the rule-based symbology under QGIS 2.18, not sure if that's what you're asking for. API reference at http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsRuleBasedRendererV2.html

```
import re
lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()    #get all loaded layers
for lyr in lddLrs:
    if (lyr.type()==QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and lyr.name()=='layer_with_rules'): rLyr = lyr

newType = 1
for child in rLyr.rendererV2().rootRule().children():
    oldFilter = child.filterExpression()  #you can print this to see what the old expression is
    print oldFilter

    newFilter = re.sub(r"type = (\d*)", r"type = {0}".format(newType), oldFilter)  #this is an example to substitute a rule-based filter to a new number
    print newFilter

    child.setFilterExpression(newFilter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as you said, I think this only applies to _symbology_ and not **labels** :)