# More than one QgsPalLayerSettings for a layer

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

Can more than one `QgsPalLayerSettings` object be defined for a single vector layer? For a line layer, I would like to put some text above the line, then some text below the line, not sure if this is possible or how

Comment: I do not think multiple `QgsPalLayerSettings` can be used for a single layer. One potential method could be to use **rule-based** labelling with one rule having the text above the line, the other rule having the text below the line. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem currently possible as I [asked a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226491/controlling-rule-based-labelling-using-pyqgis) for this a while ago not it hasn't been exposed to the API yet. I think the only workaround is to duplicate your layer and set each of their labelling properties independtly :)