# Toggle labels on/off for a layer with PyQGIS 2?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

I try to toggle labels on/off for a layer in QGIS 2.18 with PyQGIS. In PyQGIS 3 a method `QgsVectorLayer().setLabelsEnabled()` seem to have been added, but as far as I see, such is not available in PyQGIS 2 (There is no such hint *Since QGIS 3.0* as well in the doku for PyQGIS 3 https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a4cdece41437b32f4adafeb1caa10ad1b).

My first try was to access the labeling configuration of the layer with sth. like

```
label_settings = my_layer.labeling().settings()
label_settings.enabled = not label_settings.enabled
my_layer.setLabeling(label_settings)
```

but the `labeling()` and `setLabeling()` methods are not available in the python bindings (e.g. https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ada12f21c42e2f3c2eaa2b234ff25ed28).

There is a method `QgsVectorLayer().enableLabels()` as well, but this is deprecated (https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ae7735460da1518febff85575851b8e88) and seems to have no effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", True) # On
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", False) # Off
```

Comment: I just noticed, that this approach has no effect for layers with rule based labels, just for 'normal' labels. I noticed in addition that disabling labeling via gui/dialogue for a layer with rule based labels causes the existing rules to be deleted. I think that keeping them for later re-enabling rule based labeling would be worth another question...

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - You are correct in that this does not affect rule-based labels as mentioned in the comments of [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226347/how-to-turn-on-off-all-labels-of-all-layers-in-qgis/226360#226360). I also [asked a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226491/controlling-rule-based-labelling-using-pyqgis) regarding using PyQGIS specifically for rule-based labels and this was introduced for QGIS 3. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Greatly! Can not wait for QGIS 3.4 to become LTR...