# PyQGIS - Print Layout Label text size

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I'm adding a label to a Print Layout using python. I do so with the following code:

```
label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
label.setText("This is my map label")
label.adjustSizeToText()
layout.addLayoutItem(label)
layout.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(0.25, 0.25, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutInches))   #repositions map label
```

The label is small font by default and I want to resize it, but cannot figure it out. [After looking at the documentation for QgsLayoutItemLabel()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayoutItemLabel.html?highlight=qgslayoutitemlabel#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemLabel) there is no method to set the text label size.

The problem here is label.setText(), creates a string with the text.  I could modify the size of the label but only if the string is some kind of text object?

[In this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226491/controlling-rule-based-labelling-using-pyqgis/231969) in the first answer, the person created a QgsPalLayerSettings() object, which he then formatted.

[I found a helpful example in the source code for the QuickPrint plugin](https://github.com/MarcoDuiker/QGIS_QuickPrint/blob/d1c946a7b6187553c92ffad7a0cc23d39a1bc593/quick_print3.py#L299). The author gets user input via a dialog box using the following line:

```
titel = self.dlg.titelFld.text()
```

Here he converts this input to text using the text() method, but I can't figure out how to apply text() method to a string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QgsLayoutItemLabel class` has a [setFont](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemLabel.html#a8d40170a6ce888a7ba6daf577dbbf55e) method which takes a QFont object.

So you could try modifying your script like this:

```
label.setText("This is my map label")
label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 14)) #Change to your desired font and size
label.adjustSizeToText()
```

Depending on what your import statements look  like, you may need to import QFont first like:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
```