# Pause Labeling in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

Is it possible to pause/stop labeling temporarily in QGIS like in Arcmap for all layers at once?

The label toolbar offers no solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### QGIS 3.x

You could use the following code in the **Python Console** to create a button on the toolbar which toggles the labels for all vector layers:

```
action = QAction(QIcon(""), "Turn labels" + "\n" + "ON/OFF", iface.mainWindow())
action.setCheckable(True)
iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

def label_control():
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            if action.isChecked() == True:
                layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
            else:
                layer.setLabelsEnabled(False)
        layer.triggerRepaint()

action.triggered.connect(label_control)
# Uncomment line below if you want to remove the icon yourself,
# otherwise it will be removed automatically when you restart QGIS
iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
```

Code was based on the question: [How to turn on/off all labels of all layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226347/how-to-turn-on-off-all-labels-of-all-layers-in-qgis).

---

### QGIS 2.18.x

You can use the **Deactivate/Active Labels** plugin which has a button to switch on/off labels for all layers:

[image: Invert labels]

Comment: Thank you Joseph. That's what i was looking for. Too bad, it's not ported for Qgis 3 yet.

Comment: @RolandG - Most welcome, added a possible method for QGIS 3 :)

Comment: missing the Deactivate/Active labels plugin! Started a [request on their repo](https://github.com/CarlosCagna/DeactivateActiveLabels/issues/3) to upgrade it.

Comment: @nikhilvj - Nice one! :)