# Toggle labels from toolbar in QGIS 3

Tags: labeling, qgis-3

I recall having a label-toggle button in the toolbar in earlier QGIS (2.x). If the selected layer had labels configured, then clicking this button would toggle their visibility off or on. The labels' formatting, placement etc would remain unchanged.. they'd just go visible or invisible. It was very useful functionality, particularly when I had to zoom out of one area and move to another. I'd toggle the labels off when I didn't need them - it also sped up the tool's response time. Can't figure out how to get that button again in QGIS 3. I can't remember if it was some specific plugin that did it, and now can't find any such plugin.

What do I need to do to get the toggle labels button back?

EDIT: Same question asked and answered here: [Pause Labeling in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287539/pause-labeling-in-qgis)

And yes it was the [Deactivate/Active Labels plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DeactivateActiveLabels/) -> edit: plugin available in QGIS 3 now.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Pause Labeling in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287539/pause-labeling-in-qgis)

Comment: @Joseph thanks! Can some mod mark this question as a duplicate of that one? I didn't find that when searching the forum because of my choice of words.. it would be good to leave this up so folks searching with these keywords can find that one.

Comment: The Deactivate/Active Labels plugin was the one I was looking for. I've started a [request at the repo](https://github.com/CarlosCagna/DeactivateActiveLabels/issues/3) for upgrading to make the plugin QGIS 3.x compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by installing plugins.

With the **Deactivate Active Labels** plugin, you can deactivate and activate the labels for all layers in the project or do it for a specific layer.

Also, there is another plugin, **Layer Tree Toggle Labels Widget**, that adds a widget to activate and deactivate the labels for a specific layer. To use it, right click the layer, then select *Properties...*. Then, in the tab *Legend*, add the *Toggle labels* to the *Used widgets* box. Press *Ok* to close the *Layer Properties* box and a widget will be added to your layer, allowing you to activate and deactivate the labels.

Comment: does this mean that plugin is now available for QGIS 3.x and above ?

Comment: Yes, I've tested both plugins in 3.10.4 and they are working well