# How to turn off a layer's labels programmatically in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, qgis-3

I'm trying to turn off QGIS3 (3.2) labels via pyqgis per [How to turn on/off all labels of all layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226347) . I adapted the code in QGIS 2 answers linked above, as follows:

```
#...
def toggleAllLabels(self):
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():       
        if self.toggleLabelsAction.isChecked() == True:      
            layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", True)
        else:
            layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", False)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

But this doesn't work to turn off the labels. The layers refreshes, but the labels remain.

Is `layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", False)` still the right way to turn off layer labels in QGIS 3? (Or, what's the current way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `setLabelsEnabled` method on layers. Here's me disabling labels on the first layer on my map canvas from the python console:

```
iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0].setLabelsEnabled(False)
iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0].triggerRepaint()
```

cribbed from https://www.queryxchange.com/q/23_289302/pyqgis-3-how-to-use-data-defined-property-for-labeling/

More authoritative source here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/api_break.dox#L364